# Java Iterator Creation

Tags: java, iterator

I need to create an iterator for an existing sparsematrix object, but I'm missing something in my code:

```
public Iterator<SparseMatrix.Entry<E>> iterator() {
        return new EntryIterator();
    }
```

then:

```
private class EntryIterator implements Iterator<SparseMatrix.Entry<E>> {
        // Possible approach:
        // Consider the use of firstEntry() and higherEntry() methods
        // defined in TreeMap.
        Map.Entry<Position, E> mapEntry = map.firstEntry();
        Iterator<E> itr = (Iterator<E>) ((SparseMatrix<E>) mapEntry).iterator() //BOLD

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return itr.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public SparseMatrix.Entry<E> next() {
            E v = itr.next();
            return (pco.smatrix.SparseMatrix.Entry<E>) v;
        }}
```

For some reason, the iterator I've built isn't working properly. In addition, the map reference refers to a `TreeMap` object, which is then used to create a `TMSparseMatrix` one, and for some reason the //BOLD line is messing up the entire code. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hasNext` is wrong, since it calls `itr.next()`, which already advances the `itr` iterator.

Change it to:

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return itr.hasNext();
    }
```